# Reason for using CharSequence as parameter in String replace method

Tags: java

Is there a logical explanation why some methods in String class have parameters with CharSequence type and others with String type?
For example:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

and

```
public boolean startsWith(String prefix)
```

Why replace method does not use String for its parameters just like startsWith method does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a logical explanation why some methods in String class have parameters with CharSequence type and others with String type?

Short answer: **Backwards compatibility.**

[`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) was added in Java 1.4.

[`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) was added in Java 1.5, so it could use the already existing `CharSequence` type.

[`startsWith(String prefix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) has existed since Java 1.0, so it couldn't use the non-existing `CharSequence` type at the time, and couldn't be modified in Java 1.4 (or later) because that would cause *backwards compatibility* issues.

> Why replace method does not use String for its parameters just like startsWith method does?

So you can pass other types of objects which implement `CharSequence`.

Comment: That makes sense. I assume that according to your answer if CharSequence were present since Java 1.0 then probably it would be used in startsWith method signature as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about backward compatibility application here. Backward compatible means that Java 1.5 runs older versions of bytecode. It doesn't guarantee that new version runs on 1.0. In 1.5 String **is** CharSequence. So, theoretically, from inheritance perspective, older versions of bytecode should be fine to run on the new version. But I'm not sure about this specific nuance and too lazy to create an experiment :)

Comment: @FBI Signature matching happens in the JVM too when it loads bytecode, and since `startsWith(String)` and `startsWith(CharSequence)` would be two different methods, if they changed the method, all existing bytecode calling the method would fail with `NoSuchMethodError`. Sure, recompiling would fix that, but Java's backwards compatibility support includes bytecode level compatibility, so existing methods cannot be removed without going through years of *deprecated* warnings.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for clarification. I was not sure about bytecode level behavior in this case.  And yes, I meant bytecode level compatibility, otherwise it's too obvious to recompile everything :)

Answer (score 2):

### `CharSequence`

There are more classes than just `String` which implement readable char sequences, i.e. are *similar to `String`*.

The interface `CharSequence` represents those, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html):

> A `CharSequence` is a **readable sequence of `char` values**. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of char sequences. [...]

Currently known implementing classes are `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`. As you see, `String` is just one of them, there are more.

---

### Modularity

If your method takes in `CharSequence` then it is much more modular as it can also take in those other *string-ish* classes.

Obviously, `CharSequence` is a bit limited in its capabilities (check its offered methods). So not all string-like methods can be done on `CharSequence`. Sometimes you need the extra functionality that is offered by `String`, then you can not operate on `CharSequence`.

This is a very basic concept, much like some things can be done on `Animal` but others, like `bark()` can only be done with `Dog`.

---

### `replace` and `startsWith`

In your specific example the reason is actually **backwards compatibility**.

The interface `CharSequence` was added in **Java 1.4**, it was not present since the beginning.

However, `startsWith`, while it could theoretically work with `CharSequence`, was added in **Java 1.0** already, where it was not available yet.

`replace` was added with **Java 1.5**, so after `CharSequence` was a thing.

Due to **backwards compatibility**, Java creators can not just edit the `startsWith` and let it use `CharSequence` instead. It has to keep using `String`.